# Gradle cannot resolve dependencies from a private nexus repository

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, nexus

I'm trying to set up a new Gradle project, while being on a corporate network that has heavily restricted internet access (basically only the company related websites are allowed through it)
I've got a local installation of gradle (8.1.1), and i'm trying to connect to a private Nexus repository for dependencies.

Here's my build.gradle.kts file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("http://company.nexus.url/maven-repository")
        credentials {
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

If i try to reload the project in IntelliJ, it tells me `Could not resolve org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1 Possible solution: Declare repository providing the artifact`
If i try to use the command line to do `gradle dependencies` it tells me that junit-bom FAILED with no further explanations.

Adding -d to `gradle dependencies` shows me that the connection to the nexus repository works, and that it can access the pom file for the dependencies and downloads it. going to the nexus web interface, i can also see that the .jar file is available next to the pom file.

What could the issue be here? The nexus repository is hosting everything for maven projects, so could it be that something is missing in the pom file that gradle requires? And if yes, is there any way to circumvent that without modifying the repository files?

Comment: Can other artifacts from the same repo be resolved correctly? If so, check the artifact in your repo. If not, check that the repo is reachable and configured correctly.

Comment: I tried with other artifacts and none of them are reachable with gradle (they work fine with maven)

Comment: Can you build by Gradle from the command line? If not, what error are you getting?

Comment: Running `gradle dependencies` has a build successful, however it fails to get the dependencies
``` 
testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
\--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3 FAILED
```